# Data type in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Thanks to all of you guys the atof somehow works this time. And I forgot to mention that it is a C++ class so some of the code is seeming complicated to me:)

The original question is:

> write a program that will find the min, max, or mean of a set of
>   floating point numbers. The first argument to your program will be a
>   string that specifies which operation the user desires: `min'',`
>   max'', `sum'', or`mean''. All other arguments are numbers.

If main is defined to accept arguments

```
int main (int argc, char** argv[])
```

and let's say it is compiled into an executable file anexe.exe, the way to use the program we learnt in class is type the following in the cmd or shell:
anexe max 1 2 3 4 5

===========

**My question is:**

The arguments should be put in an array argv[], and argv[0] is the file name, argv[1] is the string min/max/sum/mean , and argv[2] and later should be numbers. But What is the data type of these? Are they char ? If so, how can I convert them to the float?

===========
My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::string option = std::string(argv[1]);

if (argc >1)
{
    int i = 2;
    if ( option == "min")
        {
            float least = atof (argv[2]);
            for( i = 2;i <=(argc-1);i++)
            {
                int temp = atof(argv[i]);
                if (temp < least)
                {least = temp;}
            }
            cout <<"\n"<<least; 
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `argv`? Ergo, what is the datatype of `argv[i]`? So you need to know how to turn a `char*` into a `float`. You have many options, but I'd personally consider using a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: look here  [link](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=C+convert+char*+to+float)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a homework question and the edit's should not have been approved as it is now the original question + a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your compiler you should have:

```
atof( char *str );
```

that converts char to float, and as pointed out by my colleague, you'll have:

```
char* argv[]
```

not, char** argv[];

Answer (score 1):

First, it is

```
char* argv[]
```

not

```
char** argv[]
```

And the data type of `argv[x]` is `char*`
ie. a (pointer to) an array of many char´s,
unknown count, but terminated with `\0`.
=A C-style string.

To convert it to an int-type,
use, for example, `atoi` or `sscanf`.

Comment: That's just the professor's habit I assume? Use a pointer to pointer. And it works.

Comment: Also is there any "include" I should use to use atof ?

Comment: If you´ve turned off compiler warnings and/or you´re casting like insane, then yes. But nothing of these things is good practice. stdlib.h

Comment: @user3275943: it's either `char **argv` *or* `char *argv[]`; `char **argv[]` is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[i]` will have type `char *`; your value arguments will be string representations of floating-point numbers, like `"3.1415"`.  To convert a string representation of a floting-point number to it's floating-point equivalent, you can do one of the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
double val;
int success = sscanf( argv[i], "%f", &val );
if ( success == 0 )
  // argv[i] is not a valid floating-point number string
```

or

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
double val;
char *chk;
val = strtod( argv[i], &chk );
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  // argv[i] is not a valid floating-point number string
```

The second method catches errors that the first won't, so it's the one I prefer.

Answer (score -1):

```
int value = atoi(argv[1].c_str());
```

should be a little helpful.